# Haskell program outputs `<<loop>>`

Tags: debugging, haskell, compilation, ghc, haskell-platform

I wrote a Haskell program that preforms a binary search on a list. At least that's what I thought it does. When I compiled the program with `ghc v7.6.3` and ran the program I got the following output:

```
progname: <<loop>>
```

What on earth does this output mean? Does it mean I had an infinite loop that `ghc` optimized away? How am I supposed to debug this?

Comment: Are you aware of the ghci debugger?  You can also re-purpose HPC to find out which code is NOT being executed as a way to narrow down a loop.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson GHCI raises: `Exception: <<loop>>`. I assume the compiled output `progname: <<loop>>` is and STDERR message. Does this mean I have an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes, it's the RTS (runtime system) detecting an infinite loop (which it can do in certain cases).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson @Fixnum If one of you composes an answer describing that `<<loop>>` is an exception raise by the runtime system in the event of a detectable infinite loop, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It's specifically when it detects the infinite loop that results when evaluating a specific constructor requires evaluating that constructor.

Comment: @Carl Thanks, I found the problem, had `c = k - c` instead of `c = k - n`. The circular reference is what raise the exception. Surprised that compiled...!?

Comment: @awashburn You can have self-referential values that are fully defined. `fibs = 0 : scanl (+) 1 fibs`, for instance. That's why it's allowed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As several of the comments have said, this is the Haskell RTS detecting an infinite loop at run-time. It [cannot *always* detect such loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), but in simple cases it can.

For example,

```
x = x + 1
```

will compile just fine, but provoke an exception at run-time. (Incidentally, this is an *exception* - in particular, you can *catch* it if you want. But you probably don't "want".)

So why does GHC even let this compile? Well, because if I replace `+` with, say, `:`, then the expression now terminates just fine. (It represents a 1-element circular list.) The compiler can't tell at compile-time what is and is not sensible recursion. The RTS can't always tell at run-time; but when it *can* tell something's wrong, it'll let you know by throwing an exception at you.

Comment: Is there any way to force Haskell to also output *which* infinite loop it found?

Comment: @Bakuriu Sadly no. About the best you could do is try to catch the exception and print out where you caught it from - but that would require you to have some idea where to start looking in the first place. Usually loop bugs are something as silly as a typo (e.g., you meant `x = foo y` but accidentally wrote `x = foo x`).

Comment: @Bakuriu If you compile with profiling enabled, the following will tell you where the exception was throw: `./progName +RTS -xc -RTS`

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Could you add your example ( x = foo x) to your answer? I know this is an old question but I was just sent here from google with the same error and it was a simple issue like what you said. That may provide value to other haskell noobs like myself (and comments aren't forever).

Comment: The comment from @recursion.ninja is what those who land on this question are looking for.