# Getting a <<loop>> when implementing block-visibility in a type-checker

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, typechecking

I'm writing a simple type-checker for a simple imperative language, and I'm currently stuck with this kind of output:

```
TestChecker: <<loop>>
```

I have alread read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21505192/510937) question, so I know that I must be doing something wrong with a circular reference. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the following function, which is responsible for checking a block of statements:

```
checkGroup :: Environ -> [Prog] -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkGroup env progs = (finalState, finalEnv, messages)
    where (finalState, finalEnv, messages) = foldl checkSingleProg (Ok, empty, []) progs
          checkSingleProg (s, e, msg) prog = (resS, mergeEnv e e', mess)
              where (s', e', msg') = checkProg (mergeEnv' env finalEnv) prog
                    mess = msg ++ msg'
                    resS = if s == Err || s' == Err then Err else Ok
```

Note the:

```
checkProg (mergeEnv' env finalEnv) prog
```

Where `checkProg` uses as environment the merging of the environment of the father of the  `Group` plus the environment generated by the whole `Group`.

(Edit: Yes I know that `finalEnv` is part of the output of this call to `checkProg`. *That's* the point of the question. I **know** it can be done, I just don't understand exactly what I'm doing wrong with this trick.)

The `mergeEnv'` function simply does a union between the environments (it preferes the *right* argument, as opposed to `M.union`), but keeping the left-argument's variables. It's definition is:

```
-- variables, functions, labels [for goto]
type Environ = (M.Map String Type, M.Map String Type, S.Set String)

mergeEnv' :: Environ -> Environ -> Environ
mergeEnv' env1 env2 = (fst' env1,
                       M.union (snd' env2) (snd' env1),
                       S.union (thr' env2) (thr' env1))
```

(The `mergeEnv` (no apos at the end) simply does all three unions.)

The `Prog` type is the type of statements (e.g. `If`, `For`, `Group` etc.)
The `State` type is either `Ok` or `Err`, to signal successful and unsuccessful checking.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have block-visibility for function definitions (and labels) and forward visibility for variables, without doing two different runs.

If I change:

```
(mergeEnv' env finalEnv)
```

To:

```
env
```

Everything runs "fine", but the visibility is forward only for everything.

I *know* that it's possible to achieve what I want in a way very similar to what I'm trying (I got the idea from my professor of Languages and Compilers), however it seems like I'm doing something wrong with the merging of the environments.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Or should this work and the problem is probably hidden somewhere else in the type-checker?

---

Here's a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem. However it's still about 180 lines:

```
module Main where


import qualified Data.Map as M


data Prog = Group [Prog]
          | Fdecl Type String [(Type, String)] Prog
          | Simple Simple
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Simple = Rexp Rexp
            | Vdecl Type String Rexp
            | Return Rexp
    deriving (Eq, Show)


data Rexp = Call String [Rexp]
          | Lexp Lexp
          | Const Const
    deriving(Eq, Show)


data Lexp = Ident String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Const = Integer Integer
    deriving (Eq, Show)


data Type = Func Type [Type]
          | Int
          | Error
    deriving (Eq, Show)




compatible :: Type -> Type -> Bool
compatible _ Error = True
compatible x y | x == y = True
compatible (Func ty types) (Func ty' types') = compatible ty ty' && and (zipWith compatible types types')
compatible _ _ = False




type Environ = (M.Map String Type, M.Map String Type)

empty :: Environ
empty = (M.empty, M.empty)


hasVar :: Environ -> String -> Bool
hasVar env var = M.member var $ fst env

getVarType :: Environ -> String -> Type
getVarType env var = fst env M.! var

putVar :: Environ -> String -> Type -> Environ
putVar env var ty = (M.insert var ty $ fst env, snd env)

hasFunc :: Environ -> String -> Bool
hasFunc env func = M.member func $ snd env

getFuncType :: Environ -> String -> Type
getFuncType env func = snd env M.! func

putFunc :: Environ -> String -> Type -> Environ
putFunc env func ty = (fst env, M.insert func ty $ snd env)

vars :: Environ -> M.Map String Type
vars = fst

funcs :: Environ -> M.Map String Type
funcs = snd


mergeEnv :: Environ -> Environ -> Environ
mergeEnv env1 env2 = (M.union (fst env2) (fst env1),
                      M.union (snd env2) (snd env1))


mergeEnv' :: Environ -> Environ -> Environ
mergeEnv' env1 env2 = (fst env1,
                       M.union (snd env2) (snd env1))



data State = Ok | Err
    deriving (Eq, Show)





checkProg :: Environ -> Prog -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkProg env prog = case prog of
                          Group progs -> checkGroup env progs
                          Fdecl retType name params body -> checkFdecl env retType name params body
                          Simple simple -> checkSimple env simple

checkSimple :: Environ -> Simple -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkSimple env simple = case simple of
                              Rexp expr -> checkExpr expr
                              Vdecl typ name expr -> checkVdecl env typ name expr
                              Return expr -> (Ok, empty, [])
    where checkExpr expr = let (t, msg) = checkRExpr env expr
                           in if t == Error
                                 then (Err, empty, msg)
                                 else (Ok, empty, msg)

checkGroup :: Environ -> [Prog] -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkGroup env progs = (finalState, finalEnv, messages)
    where (finalState, finalEnv, messages) = foldl checkSingleProg (Ok, empty, []) progs
          checkSingleProg (s, e, msg) prog = (resState, mergeEnv e e', message)
              where (s', e', msg') = checkProg (mergeEnv' env finalEnv) prog
                    message = msg ++ msg'
                    resState = if s == Err || s' == Err then Err else Ok

checkFdecl :: Environ -> Type -> String -> [(Type, String)] -> Prog -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkFdecl env rTy name params body = (s, putFunc empty name funType, msg)
    where funType = Func rTy [t | (t,_) <- params]
          paramEnv = (M.fromList [(x, ty) | (ty, x) <- params], M.empty)
          baseEnv = mergeEnv paramEnv (putFunc env name funType)
          (s, e', msg) = checkProg baseEnv body

checkVdecl :: Environ -> Type -> String -> Rexp -> (State, Environ, [String])
checkVdecl env ty name expr = if t == Error
                                 then (Err, empty, msg)
                                 else if compatible t ty
                                         then (Ok, putVar empty name ty, msg)
                                         else (Err, empty, msg ++ errMsg)
    where (t, msg) = checkRExpr env expr
          errMsg = ["Incompatible assignment of type: " ++ show t ++ " to a variable of type: " ++ show ty]


checkRExpr env expr = case expr of
                           Const _-> (Int, [])
                           Lexp lexp -> checkLExpr env lexp
                           Call name params -> checkCall env name params

checkLExpr env lexp = if env `hasVar` name
                         then (getVarType env name, [])
                         else (Error, ["Undefined identifier: " ++ name])
    where (Ident name) = lexp

checkCall env name params = if not $ env `hasFunc` name
                               then (Error, ["Undefined function: " ++ name])
                               else let (Func retTy paramsTy) = getFuncType env name
                                    in if length params /= length paramsTy
                                          then (Error, ["wrong number of arguments."])
                                          else if and $ zipWith checkParam paramsTy params
                                                  then (retTy, [])
                                                  else (Error, ["Wrong type for argument."])
    where checkParam typ param = let (t, _) = checkRExpr env param
                                 in compatible t typ



{-
def f() -> int:
    return g()

def g() -> int:
    return 1

f()
-}

testProg = Group [Fdecl Int "f" [] $ Group [Simple $ Return $ Call "g" []],
                  Fdecl Int "g" [] $ Group [Simple $ Return $ Const $ Integer 1],
                  Simple $ Rexp $ Call "f" []]


main = do
    let (s,e,msg) = checkProg empty testProg
    if s == Ok
       then putStrLn "Correct!"
       else putStrLn "Error!"
    putStrLn $ concatMap (++ "\n") msg
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `finalEnv` in terms of a `foldl` and you're defining the `foldl`, via `checkProg`, in terms of `finalEnv` so it seems likely that your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: I already knew that, and I'm doing that *on purpose*. I *know* that there is a way of doing that without causing the `<<loop>>`. I *know* that it is possible because I have some code (which *works*) from my professor that does exactly that. My question is: how can I modify the code so that it doesn't cause the `<<loop>>` using this idea.

Comment: If there are *important details* like that then it is *judicious* to mention them clearly in the question so answerers don't *waste* their valuable *time* trying to help you with something you already know.

Comment: @TomEllis I completely agree with what you're saying, but I think that in this case this actually *is* mentioned rather clearly in the question.

Comment: @kosmikus: Bakuriu said "I must be doing something wrong with a circular reference" but didn't say he/she knew that it was `finalEnv` that was causing the problem.

Comment: Quote from my own question: "Note the: `checkProg (mergeEnv' env finalEnv) prog`

Where `checkProg` uses as environment the merging of the environment of the father of the `Group` plus the environment generated by the whole `Group`." I believed that would be enough to clear this point.