# Why is Object.prototype instanceof Object false?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

Why does the following return false?

```
Object.prototype instanceof Object
```

Comment: Because Object.prototype was not made from the Object() function

Comment: But the funny thing is, `Object.prototype.toString() === "[object Object]"`.

Comment: @Aravind: `Function` was not either, but is `instanceof Object`

Comment: It's also confusing because `typeof Object.prototype` is `"object"`.

Comment: @Paul Draper: why is it confusing? It's just `type` (in terms of the language) of the object, not its ancestor name.

Comment: @zerkms, because both seem to be asking: *"Hey, is this an object?"* Of course, this behavior has a rigorous explanation, but JS types are generally confusing ("Is that a number? No, that is a *Number*. Huge difference."), and this one such case.

Comment: @Paul Draper: "because both seem to be asking" --- well, it's not true. In JS objects don't have common root. If you want to know the symbol type - you use `typeof`. If you want to check if some object has another object in its prototype chain - you use `instanceof`. They are not interchangeable.

Comment: @zerkms, they both *seem* to be asking. (Of course, that is my opinion about a *perception*, so it's hard to prove myself right or wrong.)

Comment: @Paul Draper: that's the difference between natural and programming languages. When in doubts - one must check specification, not expect and assume based on their feelings.

Comment: @zerkms, right, or in other words, the difference between *seem*, and *is*. (It applies to many other statements about a programming language. Saying an aspect of a language is "confusing" would likewise not be found in spec. It is a practical description of human comprehension, and still a valid observation.)

Comment: @Paul Draper: then I agree. If one reads programming language code based on feelings not knowledge, then any programming language is confusing. `a = a + 1;` <--- how silly is it, isn't it? Math taught us it may never be true! JS is sooooo confusing :-D

Comment: @zerkms: I totally agree. And there are [programming languages where `a = a + 1` is indeed invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21554398/1048572) :-)

Comment: @zerkms, thus Pascal's := , to avoid confusion, though C did not follow suit.

Comment: @Bergi: and even more - there are languages, where there is no assignment operator :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it basically asks whether `Object.prototype` does inherit from `Object`'s `.prototype` object: It does not.

`a instanceof b` is equivalent to `b.prototype.isPrototypeOf(a)` - it tests whether `b.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `a`. In your case, it is not *in* the chain, because it is the start of the chain itself. `isPrototypeOf` is not reflexive.

Comment: Bro - do you have a blog explaining your feelings on OLOO vs. New etc.. and prototype etc.. I like the way you express/explain. very succinct. Any site of yours I can read?

Comment: @jamesemanon: No(t yet). But you can browse [my SO answers on the topic of course](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1048572%20is%3aanswer%20votes%3a4%20.prototype) :-)

Comment: @jamesemanon: To be honest, I've never heard the term [OLOO](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md#delegation-theory) before and had to google it. But yes, that seems to be the model of thought you should (or: I do) use in JS. I like its genericy, the concept of classes can be trivially implemented by it. Using constructor functions & `new` is just syntactic sugar (like ES6 classes are, but with more "common" syntax)

Comment: @Bergi I'm confused with your answer. I think you wanted to say `b instanceof a` instead of `a instanceof b` in your particular example.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: No, it's really what I mean. `a` is the instance, `b` is the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype
>   chain the `prototype` property of a constructor.