# How can I avoid <<loop>> in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fixed-point-iteration, tying-the-knot

The program below results in `<<loop>>` in GHC.

...Obviously. In hindsight.

It happens because `walk` is computing a fixed point, but there are multiple possible fixed points. When the list comprehension reaches the end of the graph-walk, it "asks" for the next element of `answer`; but that is exactly what it's already trying to compute. I guess I figured the program would get to the, er, end of the list, and stop.

I have to admit, I'm a bit sentimental about this nice code, and wish I could make it work.

- What should I do instead?
- How can I predict when "tying the knot" (referring to the value inside the expression that says how to compute the value) is a bad idea?

```
import Data.Set(Set)
import qualified Data.Set

-- Like `Data.List.nub`, remove duplicate elements from a list,
-- but treat some values as already having been seen.
nub :: Set Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
nub _ [] = []
nub seen (x:xs) =
  if Data.Set.member x seen
  then nub seen xs
  else x : nub (Data.Set.insert x seen) xs

-- A directed graph where the vertices are integers.
successors :: Integer -> [Integer]
successors x = [(x + 2) `mod` 7, (x + 3) `mod` 7]

-- Breadth first search of a directed graph.  Returns a list of every integer
-- reachable from a root set in the `successors` graph.
walk :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
walk roots =
  let rootSet = Data.Set.fromList roots
      answer = roots ++ nub rootSet [y | x <- answer, y <- successors x]
  in answer

main = putStrLn $ show $ walk [0]
```

Comment: Maybe not as satisfying as what you are looking for, but instead of defining the final list as a fixed point, try the list of lists of visited nodes at each level.

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but in a nutshell: your problem isn't the knot-tying per se, but specifically  the use of `nub`.

Comment: If you're already pulling in `containers` for `Data.Set`, you might enjoy [`nubOrd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd).

Comment: Writing recursive data structures is like writing recursive functions; there’s no general method that allows all valid lazy circular definitions but avoids all loops, and anyway not all *unproductive* definitions contain cyclic thunks that throw `NonTermination`. But large classes of problems can be solved by organising code according to principles like “**only look back**”—use monotonic “indices” to avoid logical cycles, just like a recursive base case & structural recursion—and “**do not touch**”—avoid examining circular structures till the “end” of a computation to avoid accidental cycles.

Comment: some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+corecursive+queue) which could be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one idea of how to fix it: well, we need a termination condition, right? So let's keep enough structure to know when we should terminate. Specifically, instead of producing a stream of nodes, we'll produce a stream of frontiers, and stop when the current frontier is empty.

```
import Data.Set(Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

-- Like `Data.List.nub`, but for nested lists. Order in inner lists is not
-- preserved. (A variant that does preserve the order is not too hard to write,
-- if that seems important.)
nestedNub :: Set Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
nestedNub _ [] = []
nestedNub seen (xs_:xss) = S.toList xs : nestedNub (seen `S.union` xs) xss where
  xs = S.fromList xs_ `S.difference` seen

-- A directed graph where the vertices are integers.
successors :: Integer -> [Integer]
successors x = [(x + 2) `mod` 7, (x + 3) `mod` 7]

walk :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
walk roots =
  let answer = nestedNub S.empty
        $ roots
        : [[y | x <- frontier, y <- successors x] | frontier <- answer]
  in concat $ takeWhile (not . null) answer

main = print $ walk [0]
```

There is almost certainly no general algorithm for knowing when tying the knot is a bad idea -- my gut says that's a halting problem thing, though I admit I didn't try to work out the details!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code suggests we should be able to retrieve at least the `root` prefix of `answer`, as it doesn't depend on the knot-tying. And sure enough:

```
GHCi> take 1 $ walk [0]
[0]
```

We can even go some way further:

```
GHCi> take 7 $ walk [0]
[0,2,3,4,5,6,1]
```

As soon as we ask for the eight element, though, we get stuck:

```
GHCi> take 8 $ walk [0]
[0,2,3,4,5,6,1
```

(Interestingly, trying it in GHCi doesn't seem to trip [the <<loop>> detector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41517506/2751851), unlike with a compiled program.)

That the problem only shows up when going beyond the seventh element of a list of unique modulo 7 integers points at the heart of the matter. Removing `nub` from your definition gives us a perfectly fine infinite list:

```
walkWithDuplicates :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
walkWithDuplicates roots =
  let rootSet = Data.Set.fromList roots
      answer = roots ++ [y | x <- answer, y <- successors x]
  in answer
```

```
GHCi> (!! 9999) $ walkWithDuplicates [0]
2
```

Using `nub` on an infinite list is risky business. If the number of distinct elements in it is finite, at some point there will not be a next element to be produced.

What to do, then? If we know in advance the size of the graph, as in your example, we can merrily cheat:

```
walkKnownSize :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
walkKnownSize roots =
  let graphSize = 7
      rootSet = Data.Set.fromList roots
      answer = roots ++ nub rootSet [y | x <- answer, y <- successors x]
  in take graphSize answer
```

```
GHCi> walkKnownSize [0]
[0,2,3,4,5,6,1]
```

(Note that specifying the graph size wouldn't at all feel like cheating were we passing your graph to the function as a triple of size, roots and an `Int -> Integer -> [Integer]` successors function.)

In addition to that and to [Daniel Wagner's alternative knot-tying strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66305591/2751851), I feel it is worth putting on the table a solution without knot-tying, for the sake of completeness. The implementation below is an unfold that generates the successive levels of the walk (in the spirit of [Li Yao Xia's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304661/how-can-i-avoid-loop-in-haskell#comment117221361_66304661)). That makes it possible to stop once all elements have been visited:

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)
-- etc.

walkUnfold :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
walkUnfold roots =
    let rootsSet = Data.Set.fromList roots
        nextLevel (previouslySeen, currentLevel) =
            let seen = foldr Data.Set.insert previouslySeen currentLevel
                candidates = concatMap successors currentLevel
                newlyVisited = nub seen candidates
            in case newlyVisited of
                [] -> Nothing
                _ -> Just (newlyVisited, (seen, newlyVisited))
        levels = roots : unfoldr nextLevel (Data.Set.empty, roots)
    in concat levels
```