# Haskell Langton Ant and Infinite loop

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a Langton Ant and in Haskell, the idea is that the ant will run forever, so I encoded it like this.

I have a function `stepSystem :: (Ant, Universe) -> (Ant, Universe)` that will run a single step for the ant. `Ant` here is a record with the position and the ant direction and `universe` is an 2d array of chars.

I then have a `runSystem` function that will run `stepSystem` indefinitely. The problem is that when I run this it just outputs one cycle then prints `<<loop>>` and exit. I read that this is because the Haskell runtime detected an unbounded loop, but in this case this is just what I want. What do to in this situation??

Here is the full code

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.Array
import Data.Char
import Data.Function
import qualified System.Process as SP

data Direction
  = DUp
  | DDown
  | DLeft
  | DRight

data Color
  = Black
  | White

type Pos = (Int, Int)

type Universe = Array Pos Char

data Ant =
  Ant
    { pos :: Pos
    , dir :: Direction
    }

h = 50

w = 50

start = (h `div` 2, w `div` 2)

mkArray :: (Int, Int) -> Array (Int, Int) Char
mkArray (maxx, maxy) =
  array
    ((1, 1), (maxx, maxy))
    [((i, j), '.') | i <- [1 .. maxx], j <- [1 .. maxy]]

mkUniverse :: Universe
mkUniverse = mkArray (h, w)

mkAnt :: Ant
mkAnt =
  let (x, y) = start
   in Ant {pos = (x, y), dir = DUp}

-- sleep seconds
sleep :: Int -> IO ()
sleep n = threadDelay (n * 1000000)

-- clear terminal
clear :: IO ()
clear = do
  _ <- SP.system "reset"
  return ()

colorToChar :: Color -> Char
colorToChar Black = '.'
colorToChar White = '@'

charToColor :: Char -> Color
charToColor '.' = Black
charToColor '@' = White
charToColor c = error $ "invalid char " ++ [c]

printUniverse :: Universe -> IO ()
printUniverse m = do
  forM_ (assocs m) $ \((y, x), cell) -> do
    putChar cell
    putChar '\n' & when (x == w)

turnLeft :: Direction -> Direction
turnLeft DUp = DLeft
turnLeft DDown = DRight
turnLeft DLeft = DDown
turnLeft DRight = DUp

turnRight :: Direction -> Direction
turnRight DUp = DRight
turnRight DDown = DLeft
turnRight DLeft = DUp
turnRight DRight = DDown

turnAnt :: Color -> Direction -> Direction
turnAnt White = turnRight
turnAnt Black = turnLeft

flipColor :: Color -> Color
flipColor Black = White
flipColor White = Black

flipColorChr :: Char -> Char
flipColorChr = colorToChar . flipColor . charToColor

updateCell :: Pos -> Char -> Universe -> Universe
updateCell pos chr universe = universe // [(pos, chr)]

flipCell :: Pos -> Universe -> Universe
flipCell pos universe =
  let c = flipColorChr (universe ! pos)
   in updateCell pos c universe

decrementX :: Int -> Int
decrementX x
  | x == 0 = w
  | otherwise = x - 1

incrementX :: Int -> Int
incrementX x
  | x == w = 0
  | otherwise = x + 1

incrementY :: Int -> Int
incrementY y
  | y == h = 0
  | otherwise = y + 1

decrementY :: Int -> Int
decrementY y
  | y == 0 = h
  | otherwise = y - 1

moveForward :: Direction -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
moveForward DLeft (x, y) = (decrementX x, y)
moveForward DRight (x, y) = (incrementX x, y)
moveForward DUp (x, y) = (x, decrementY y)
moveForward DDown (x, y) = (x, incrementY y)

moveAnt :: Color -> Ant -> Ant
moveAnt currentColor Ant {pos = (x, y), dir = dir} =
  let (x, y) = moveForward dir (x, y)
   in Ant {pos = (x, y), dir = turnAnt currentColor dir}

getCurrentCellColor :: Ant -> Universe -> Color
getCurrentCellColor Ant {pos = (x, y)} universe =
  charToColor $ universe ! (x, y)

stepSystem :: (Ant, Universe) -> (Ant, Universe)
stepSystem (ant@Ant {pos = pos}, universe) =
  let currentCellColor = getCurrentCellColor ant universe
      newAnt = moveAnt currentCellColor ant
   in (newAnt, flipCell pos universe)

runSystem :: (Ant, Universe) -> IO ()
runSystem system@(ant, universe) = do
  printUniverse universe
  print "---------------"
  runSystem (stepSystem system)

main :: IO ()
main = runSystem (mkAnt, mkUniverse)
```

Comment: I recommend you go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: It outputs a grid and two "---------------" before hanging.

Comment: It's already answered where to fix. For what <<loop>> means, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517506/how-does-the-loop-error-work-in-detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies here:

```
moveAnt :: Color -> Ant -> Ant
moveAnt currentColor Ant {pos = (x, y), dir = dir} =
  let (x, y) = moveForward dir (x, y)
   in Ant {pos = (x, y), dir = turnAnt currentColor dir}
```

Specifically, `(x, y) = moveForward dir (x, y)` is a self-recursive call. A bit subtle isn't it? Having name shadowing warning on would have at least pointed a possible confusion.

Changing the definition to

```
  let (x', y') = moveForward dir (x, y)
   in Ant {pos = (x', y'), dir = turnAnt currentColor dir}
```

fixes the problem. Personally I wouldn't even define x' or y': `Ant {pos = moveForward dir (x, y), dir = turnAnt currentColor dir}`.

Btw, I found the problem by running the functions in the repl:

```
λ> (ant@Ant {pos = pos}, universe) = (mkAnt, mkUniverse)
λ> printSystem (a, u) = print a >>  printUniverse u
λ> printSystem $  stepSystem $  stepSystem (ant, universe) 
Ant {pos = (^CInterrupted. -- Hangs here.
λ>
```

Of course, I had to make your data types derive Show.

Comment: Lazy evaluation bites me again, thank you Pedro I wouldn't get it by staring the code

Comment: Did you use the ghci debug or was just by trying function by function? I thought that the message <<loop>> was about any closed loop not only self referential expression. I need to get strict evaluation out of my head

Comment: Regular ghci. I also used https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=trace&scope=set%3Astackage but it was useless. Vanilla printing in ghci is more than enough.

Comment: The link in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69007794/haskell-langton-ant-and-infinite-loop/69008844?noredirect=1#comment121963529_69007794 explains  it well.

Comment: Btw, can you mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: `dir = turnAnt currentColor dir` would also be self-recursive, if it was a let or where expression

Comment: @geckos: this is not that much lazy evaluation, this is more the fact that haskell uses a `letrec` for `let` statements, where it thus can define itself recursively.

Comment: I marked as correct I will check the link too, thank you!